# Copy configuration between multiple RDC sessions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, automation, rdc

I have a requirement to configure 25 remote desktop sessions identically ready for users to connect and start using them.

The type of config that is needed is things like browsing to a site and downloading an activx control, disabling popup blockers, configuring default printers, adjusting printer properties, adding sites to the compatability mode list and some java configuration.

Basically, a lot of per user changes. No software installs just configuration of what is already there - but twenty five times.

Im looking for advice on ways that this can be automated, If it was all IE/windows changes Id be looking to use power shell but I'm thinking that some kind of mouse/keystroke record/playback might be better.

Its a one off requirement so ideally we are looking for something that we can get to grips with quickly.

Tips/suggestions welcome

Comment: There really isn't an easy way to do this any more. This is Microsoft's official and supported method. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/customize-the-default-user-profile-by-using-copyprofile

Comment: For 25 RDP sessions, one-off, I'd probably just sic the PFY on it.

Comment: Me thinks the OP is the PFY. ;)

Comment: Ha ha, no, I'm a contract software dev looking to get the test environment set up quickly! The client outsourced all of this to DXE and they are dragging their feet which is holding up the project and my payment!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like updating the default user profile on the RDS server may do the trick. That isn't as easy as it used to be but it is still possible. You can make the configuration changes in one profile and copy it to to the default profile using the delprof utility ww.forensit.com/support-downloads.html . After replacing the default user profile any new users logging on would inherit the settings from the  new default profile, any existing profiles would be unaffected.